# Prob. 2, Sec. 31, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Any pair of disjoint closed sets in a normal space have neighborhoods whose closures are disjoint

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, separation-axioms

Here is Prob. 2, Sec. 31, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Show that if $X$ is normal, every pair of disjoint closed sets have neighborhoods whose closures are disjoint.

Here is the definition of normal space:

> A topological space $X$ is said to be *normal* if
>
> (i) singleton subsets (and hence finite subsets) of $X$ are closed in $X$, and
>
> (ii) for every pair $A$ and $B$ of disjoint closed sets in $X$, there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ in $X$ containing $A$ and $B$, respectively.

My Attempt:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be any two disjoint closed sets in a normal space $X$. Then there exist disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ of $X$ such that $A \subset U$ and $B \subset V$.
>
> Now as $A$ is a closed set in the normal space $X$ and as $U$ is an open set containing $A$, so by Lemma 31.1 (b) in Munkres there is an open set $U^\prime$ in $X$ such that $A \subset U^\prime$ and  $\overline{U^\prime} \subset U$. Thus we have 
>   $$ A \subset U^\prime \subset \overline{U^\prime} \subset U. $$
>
> Similarly, as $B$ is a closed set in the normal space $X$ and as $V$ is an open set containing $B$, so there exists an open set $V^\prime$ in $X$ such that
>   $$ B \subset V^\prime \subset \overline{V^\prime} \subset V. $$
>
> Finally, as $U$ and $V$ are disjoint and as $\overline{U^\prime} \subset U$ and $\overline{V^\prime} \subset V$, so the sets $\overline{U^\prime}$ and $\overline{V^\prime}$ are also disjoint.
>
> Thus $U^\prime$ and $V^\prime$ are neighborhoods of sets $A$ and $B$ (i.e. open sets containing these sets), respectively, such that their closures $\overline{U^\prime}$ and $\overline{V^\prime}$ are disjoint.

The above proof is very similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3264303/prob-1-sec-31-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-every-pair-of-points-in-a-regula) one.

Is this proof correct? If so, is it clearly enough presented? If not, then where is it deficient?

Last but not least, does the converse also hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask also whether the converse statement:

A topological space $X$ such that every two disjoint closed sets have neighbourhoods with disjoint closure is normal.

This is clearly true: if $A, B \subset X$ are closed disjoint sets, by assumption there are open sets $A \subset U$, $B \subset V$ such that $\overline{U} \cap \overline{V} = \emptyset$. Then $U \cap V = \emptyset$ and $X$ is normal.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine, as soon as you have the closed set in open set lemma, this fact is an almost trivial consequence of that.